# Using FOR loop and summing values between rounds in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

this is my task:

"Write program LoopForNumberSum.java. Display only every second number, starting from 2, to the screen and sum in parenthesis between the last round and current round so far. The looping range is defined in separate variables. Use FOR-loop to solve the problem."

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class LoopForNumberSum {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int min = 2;
        int max = 10;

        for(int i = min; i <= max; i+=2) {
            int j = i+i;
            System.out.println(i + "(" + j + "), ");
        }
    }
}
```

^This code prints:

2(4),

4(8),

6(12),

8(16),

10(20),

But I need the number in the parenthesis to start from 2 and the rest would need to be 6, 10, 14 and 18. Like this: "2(2), 4(6)..."

Comment: Hint: You need a variable declared outside the loop to store the value so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 2 ; i <= 10 ; i += 2) {
    sum += i;
    System.out.println(i + "(" + sum + "), ");
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I'm assuming my teacher has made a mistake when he has written that the output should look like "2(2), 4(6), 6(10), 8(14), 10(18)". When actually if you sum up the previous round with the current round it prints out as "2(2), 4(6), 6(12), 8(20), 10(30)"